# Grails cannot handle one-to-one relation when child entity contains invalid data

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a parent table Parent and a child table Child. The relation is like this:

```
class Parent {
   ...
   Child child

   static mapping = {
      child lazy: false, cascade: 'all'
   }
   static constraints = { ... }
}

class Child {
   String name

   static constraints = {
      name unique: true
   }
}
```

I created some code to add a child to an existing parent. It looks like this:

```
def parent = Parent.get(id)
parent.child = new Child(name: (name))
parent.save()
```

This code is contained in a method of transactional service.

It does not work when child is invalid - no validation happens. I get a famous hibernate error:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance 
>   before flushing`.

It can be easily explained: child is not validated, when GORM saves objects, it tries to save child, then it should stop due to a failure, but it proceeds and tries to save parent with unsaved child field.

How can I work around the case when child is invalid? I need to propagate information about the error to a view form.

I've already tried to validate child manually - it's errors field contains 1 error, but parent is still valid. I've tried to insert the error to the parent errors field - parent becomes invalid, but GORM still tries to save it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have **belongsTo** defined (e.g static belongsTo = [Parent]) in your relationship between Child and Parent? If you do not, Grails will not cascade the save/update from the Parent to the Child since it doesn't "own" the Child - thus if no save is happening on the Child, then validation never gets called. So try adding

```
static belongsTo = [Parent]
```

in the Child class and saving again, possibly with [deepValidate:true](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html) as well if you're still not seeing the Child validation occurring.

Comment: No, I don't have belongsTo. The problem is that parent does not own a child (it's just an example, things are more complicated). But I don't really see a technical problem to perform deepValidation here. I found a similar issue in grails JIRA, but it's unresolved yet. (that's why I added `bug` tag).

Comment: I'm still pretty new to Grails but from my understanding, it seems like the behavior you're experiencing is correct. GORM is basically a wrapper for hibernate, and in hibernate you would also get an "object references an unsaved transient .." error if you did not explicitly define the cascading effect from a Parent to a Child, when you're saving that relationship. If you were to define a cascading effect, Hibernate would handle persisting the new Child instance, but it's still be up to the user (or whatever framework) to make sure that the Child instance is in a valid state before saving...

Comment: In the case of Grails, GORM handles the validation on save but ONLY if it was told about the relationship and ownership between the Parent and Child in the one-to-one relationship. If you can't define the ownership in your relationship, then I think you will have to manually save the Child instance before assigning it to the Parent. Maybe some one with more experience can validate/invalidate my understanding :-)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for this nice Answer i was facing same problem due to your post i resolve the problem

```
def val = (params.company).toInteger()
def parent = Company.get(val)
        .addToJobs(new Job(
            experience:params.months,
            jobdescription:params.desc,
            joblocation:params.companyloc,
            jobskills:params.skills,
            jobtype:params.emp,
            salary:params.jobsalary,
            jobtitle:params.jobtitle))
        .save()
```